# Make lexer consider parser before determining tokens?

Tags: parsing, lexer, ocamllex, ocamlyacc, menhir

I'm writing a lexer and parser in ocamllex and ocamlyacc as follows. `function_name` and `table_name` are same regular expression, i.e., a string containing only english alphabets. The only way to determine if a string is `function_name` or `table_name` is to check its surroundings. For example, if such a string is surrounded by `[` and `]`, then we know that it is a `table_name`. Here is the current code:

In `lexer.mll`,

```
... ...

let function_name = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']+
let table_name = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']+

rule token = parse
  | function_name as s { FUNCTIONNAME s }
  | table_name as s { TABLENAME s }

... ...
```

In `parser.mly`:

```
... ...

main: 
| LBRACKET TABLENAME RBRACKET { Table $2 }

... ...
```

As I wrote `| function_name as s { FUNCTIONNAME s }` before `| table_name as s { TABLENAME s }`, the above code failed to parse `[haha]`; it firstly considered `haha` as a `function_name` in the lexer, then it could not find any corresponding rule for it in the parser. If it could consider `haha` as a `table_name` in the lexer, it would match `[haha]` as a table in the parser.

One workaround for this is to be more precise in the lexer. For example, we define `let table_name_with_brackets = '[' ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']+ ']'` and `| table_name_with_brackets as s { TABLENAMEWITHBRACKETS s }` in the lexer. But, I would like to know if there is any other options. Is it not possible to make lexer and parser work together to determine the tokens and the reduction?

Comment: Why are `function_name` and `table_name` separate token types at all?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I simplified a little bit. Actually the regular expression for `function_name` is not exactly the same as `table_name`. They are not exactly the same, but they have overlapping.

Comment: Please edit that note into your question. It's an important clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid trying to get the lexer to do the parser's work. The lexer should just identify lexemes; it should not try to figured out where a lexeme fits into the syntax. So in your (simplified) example, there should be only one lexical type, `name`. The parser will figure it out from there.

But it seems, from the comments, that in the unsimplified original, the two patterns are overlapping rather than identical. That's more annoying, although it's only slightly more complicated. Basically, you need to separate out the common pattern as one lexical type, and then add the additional matches as one or two other lexical types (depending on whether or not one pattern is a strict superset of the other).

That might not be too difficult, depending on the precise relationship between the two patterns. You might be able to find a very simple solution by writing the patterns in the correct order, for example, because of the longest match rule:

> If several regular expressions match a prefix of the input, the “longest match” rule applies: the regular expression that matches the longest prefix of the input is selected. In case of tie, the regular expression that occurs earlier in the rule is selected.

Most of the time, that's all it takes: first define the intersection of the two patterns as a based lexeme, and then add the full lexical patterns of each contextual type to provide additional matches. Your parser will then have to match `name | function_name` in one context and `name | table_name` in the other context. But that's not too bad.

Where it will fail is when an input stream cannot be unambiguously divided in lexemes. For example, suppose that in a function context, a name could include a `?` character, but in a table context the `?` is a valid postscript operator. In that case, you have to actively prevent `foo?` from being analysed as a single token in the table context, which means that the lexer does have to be aware of parser context.